# Reset backgroundTimeRemaining when app goes to background

Tags: ios

Using the following code I am able to run my background app for around 180 seconds. My final objective is to keep it running forever. Battery/processor overuse is not a concern for me as I'm making this for myself.

This is code I'm using to run my app in the background.

```
UIApplication * application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
{
    NSLog(@"Multitasking Supported");
 
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
    background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
 
        //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
 
    //To make the code block asynchronous
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 
        //### background task starts
        NSLog(@"Running in the background\n");
        while(TRUE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Background time Remaining: %f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; //wait for 1 sec
        }
        //#### background task ends
 
        //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; 
    });
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Multitasking Not Supported");
}
```

`Background time remaining:` starts at around 180 seconds and by the time it comes down to 5, the app gets suspended. No matter what I try, this cannot be avoided.

My device is running iOS 8.1 and here are the methods I've tried so far:

**Method 1:**

I set background modes as location in info.plist and used the following code as shown in [this tutorial](http://hayageek.com/ios-long-running-background-task/).

`CLLocationManager * manager = [CLLocationManager new];`
`__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;`

and then

`[manager startUpdatingLocation];`

**Method 2:**

Using the following lines of code before the app enters the background state.

`CLLocationManager* locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`
`[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

I just need to reset backgroundTimeRemaining and any hack will be fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was following the updated part of [this tutorial.](http://hayageek.com/ios-long-running-background-task/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep it running in the background unless you have enabled 'Background app refresh' in your device's settings. `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` is ment to be used for cleanup purposes:

> This method lets your app continue to run for a period of time after
>   it transitions to the background. You should call this method at times
>   where leaving a task unfinished might be detrimental to your app’s
>   user experience. For example, your app could call this method to
>   ensure that had enough time to transfer an important file to a remote
>   server or at least attempt to make the transfer and note any errors.
>   You should not use this method simply to keep your app running after
>   it moves to the background.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Background app refresh is already turned on in my device. My app is not in the list though.